# Use host's VGA output from virtual machine

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, qemu, video

Is there a way to stop a host OS from using its VGA port (on the motherboard) and allow a VM to use it instead with KVM-QEMU?

I have read about VGA pass-through, but all the discussion I've found on that had to do with giving a VM control over a specific graphic card in the system rather than the motherboard's VGA port.

Comment: What, then, will the host system use for a console?

Comment: An onboard display device will appear as a PCI* device just like a discreet graphics card.

Comment: So boot the host OS with a serial console and make sure you have a system with AMD-V or Intel VT-D  ?

Comment: @MichaelHampton The host system would use serial or ssh console.

Comment: @MarkWagner Okay so then the same tutorials for passing through a graphics card should be similar to the process needed for the onboard display device. I just hadn't seen any mention of it, but I'll take that approach and see what I can get working.

Comment: @Hennes This would definitely be the first step. Thanks, I can't believe I didn't think of that. I was trying to figure out how to stop the host from using the onboard graphics after it had booted rather than just having it boot that way.